# (AHK) Confirm before loading a program.

Tags: autohotkey

Curious as to how to make a popup asking to confirm if I want to load the program before it loads. Example:

```
^g::Run C:\GW2\gw2.exe
```

Comment: The design here is for one question per post, so that a single answer can be accepted. Multiple questions means that a separate user can post an answer to each question, in which case all could be correct and no single answer is "correct". Please edit your post, make it a single question, and move your other questions into their own posts. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can provide more information about how to ask questions here (and how to improve your chances of getting an answer). It's usually better if you also post what you've tried yourself so far that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it does not seem that you have done a lot of homework, I'll provide a solution here.

```
^g::
MsgBox, 4100, , Would you like to launch GW2?, 5  ; 5-second timeout.
IfMsgBox, No
    Return  ; User pressed the "No" button.
IfMsgBox, Timeout
    Return ; Timed out.
run, C:\GW2\gw2.exe
Return
```